# error when calling agent from xpage button

Tags: xpages

I am receiving an error when trying to call an agent from an xpages button click: Error below

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=2, col=7: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesAgent.runWithDocumentContext(lotus.domino.local.Document) null

JavaScript code

```
var agent=database.getAgent("xpCreateNewCopy");
agent.runWithDocumentContext(currentDocument.getDocument());
```

Comment: And `agent` and `currentDocument.getDocument()` both have value (are not null)? If I recall correctly I once noticed the same, `runWithDocumentContext` did not work from SSJS (don't remember the Domino version).

Comment: What version of Notes/Domino? runWithDocumentContext requires 8.5.2+

Comment: 8.5.3. It returns the same error regardless of agent.run or .runwithcontext

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had missed an important setting, run as web user. Problem solved.

Comment: It will not let me flag it until tomorrow since it is my own answer